# Let $\pi : E \to B$ be a disc-bundle. Why does it induce an isomorphism in (co-)homology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, vector-bundles

I've been looking at a proof of the Gysin sequence and there the fact above is used, but I do not see how this happens. Probably it comes down to showing that the total space of a disc bundle is homotopyequivalent to the base space, but I do not see how.

Comment: Do you mean vector bundle rather than sphere bundle?  This is not true for sphere bundles...

Comment: I thought that a sphere bundle is just an example of a vector bundle.

Comment: No, they are quite different (though related)!  The fibers of a sphere bundle are spheres and the fibers of a vector bundle are vector spaces...

Comment: Okay sorry then I think I mixed up then. I meant a disc bundle. I'm going to edit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not only does $\pi$ induce isomorphisms in (co-)homology, but actually $\pi$ is a homotopy equivalence in the special case that $B$ is a CW complex. To prove this, just use obstruction theory to construct a section $B \to E$, then deformation retract $E$ to the image of that section.

The general case, where $B$ need not be a CW complex, reduces to the case of a CW complex by using the existence of a [weak homotopy equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_equivalence_(homotopy_theory)) $X \mapsto B$ from some CW complex $X$.

Comment: An alternative proof in the CW complex case is to use the long exact sequence in homotopy to show that $\pi$ is a weak homotopy equivalence, then appeal to Whitehead's theorem.